# On ServerClick event in Asp.net is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code i have window.open method in js to open a page and there is another click event.The Click event is not getting fired.When it is window.showmodal dialog the click event is firing.I remove window.showmodal dialog because chrome doesn't support it .Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPopUp", "ShowPopUp()", true);

    function ShowPopUp() {

             var sFeatures = "dialogHeight: 400px;";           
                var myWindow = window.open("/Transaction/QuoteFromVendor.aspx", "QuoteFromVendor", "width=900,height=200",sFeatures);

                  window.document.getElementById("<%= btnHiddenForUpdate.ClientID%>").click();  
            }

<input type="button" id="btnHiddenForUpdate" runat="server" style="display:none" onserverclick="btnHiddenForUpdate_ServerClick" />
```

Comment: Try `.trigger()` function for fire click event. e.g. `$("<%= btnHiddenForUpdate.ClientID%>").trigger( "click" );`

Answer (score 0):

Did you made sure that AutoEventWireup is enabled for aspx page?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind=" " Inherits=" " %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript...
```

To:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript...
```

Comment: It is open the popup window but click event is not firing